# How to redirect user to login page while adding items to cart?

Tags: django

I am newbie to django. I am creating simple order system. I want only logged in user to add items in cart. If user is not looged in, redirect user to login page and after logged in again redirect user to previous page.

This is my views.py

```html
@require_POST
@login_required
def cart_add(request, dish_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    dish = get_object_or_404(Dish, id=dish_id)
    form = CartAddDishForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(dish=dish, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Comment: Swap the `login_required` with the `@require_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You should swap the decorators. Right now the view function is first decorated with `@login_required`, and then decorated with `@require_POST`. But that means that if you make a request that is *not* a POST request, it will return a 405 error, regardless whether the user is logged in.

By swapping the decorators, it will first check if the user is logged in, if that is not the case, it will redirect the user to the login view. If the user is logged in, but the method is not POST, it will return a 405 error.

```
@login_required
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, dish_id):
    # …
```

Note that redirecting to `cart_add` however does not make much sense, since it requires a POST request, and this thus means that it will raise a 405 after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cart_add(request, dish_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated: #checks user is logined or not
        cart = Cart(request)
        dish = get_object_or_404(Dish, id=dish_id)
        form = CartAddDishForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            cart.add(dish=dish, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
        return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
    else:
        return redirect('login_page')
```

Comment: What is the use of login_required? When should I use it?